# IntelliJ IDEA 14 Copy and Paste not working with other applications

Tags: intellij-idea, windows-10, intellij-14

Couldn't find the simple solution on SO, so thought I would add this here for anyone looking in the future.

My symptom was that I could copy and paste within the IJ editor, but **not from the editor to another application** or from another app to the editor.

This was on Windows 10 with IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.6.

Comment: I don't know if this will work with other situations. Here is my story: I tried to copy sql query from Dbeaver to goland and it was not pasting into the editor. But when I copy same the text from dbeaver to other place (as a example here: https://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) and then again copy it from the other place only then I am able to paste into the goland iDE

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My solution (thanks to [a similar issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=173201) reported with Android Studio) was to **run IntelliJ as an admin.**

Steps to always run IntelliJ in admin mode:

1. Right-click on IntelliJ icon in start menu search (or wherever you started it) -> **Open file location**
2. Right-click IntelliJ **shortcut** -> **Open file location** (yes, again to get to the .exe, not the shortcut.)
3. Right-click **idea.exe** -> **Properties**
4. **Compatibility** tab -> check **Run this program as an Administrator**
5. Right-click **idea64.exe** -> **Properties** (if you run IntelliJ in 64 bit mode)
6. **Compatibility** tab -> check **Run this program as an Administrator**

Comment: Solved it for me, but I'm a little concerned that I needed to give any application admin rights to use copy/paste functionality. It didn't feel comfortable opening up permissions like that.

Comment: @Jeremy I completely agree.  This is definitely not an ideal solution, but it happens to work.  This is a known bug in several flavors of IntelliJ.  Last time I checked the issue, it sounded like they would be rolling out a fix in an upcoming build.

Comment: Should not be marked correct imo. See the answer by @onmyway, the issue is overzealous Vim emu. This is needless/dangerous elevation of privileges

Comment: @pixelpax agreed Vim emu can be the culprit, but I didn't have any Vim plugins installed.    The ideal fix is running a version without this bug.  But this is an immediate solution if that's what is required.

Answer (score 16):

I have found the best solution yet (for me in any case). I have tried everything! Including adding and removing Keymap options. And this is actually where the problem lies...sort of.

When you have the Vim plugin installed, `Ctrl + c` and `Ctrl + v` is allocated to Vim.

To change that, go to **Setting**>>**Other Settings**>>**Vim Emulation** and set the **Handler** to **IDE**. Apply and OK, and Voila!

[image]

Comment: Yes, this fixed it for me. In 2021.1.2 these settings are under Editor > Vim, but everything else is identical still... I can't believe they haven't solved this problem over the last 4 years

Answer (score 3):

Same problem drove me completely insane but this 
https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Ctrl+V-and-Ctrl+C-work-in-IntelliJ-IDEA-14-0-2-on-Linux
worked for me:

You might try **Ctrl+INS** for copy and **Shift+INS** for paste and see if they work. They are the traditional cut and paste and have been around a lot longer than Ctrl+c/Ctrl+v.

i don't know why, but this worked!

Answer (score 2):

To make copy/paste through shortcut keys working with Vim Plugin you need to change some settings of Intellij IDE's **editor** regarding **vim emulation**, you need to follow these steps for it:

1. Click Menu **File > Settings...** (or use shortcut **Ctrl + Alt + S**)
2. Select **Editor -> Vim Emulation** and find the shortcuts and change their Handler column value to IDE as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

The Shortcuts will start working, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution i've found
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=173201
 was:

Try to minimize Idea window and move it on the same monitor where is the code that you want to copy and paste it. After this small minimize and move exercise the clipboard starts working.

Ctrl-Shft-V starts working after this for me!!!!!

Comment: I have the same problem in WebStorm which is a related product. The problem appears intermittently, don't know why. What I've done is restart WebStorm and that seems to help but is very distracting for the flow of programming.

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable "Use national layouts". Settings- Keymap.

For some reason it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm - Setting>>Vim Emulation Set - Control + V/P/A to IDE

Comment: This answer adds nothing over the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the Keymap from XWin to Windows.

[image]

I don't have the any VIM plugins and running an IDE as with admin rights is silly, so the other answers were not relevant to me.

I run my IDE via gWSL, so Windows is the host OS but the IDE is running in Linux.