# JetBrains Rider: Selecting text trigger 'insert' button

Tags: jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-rider

I have a strange issue with JetBrains Rider.

I write some text and then when I select a text with my mouse, to replace it or to copy it, suddenly, it seems like the 'insert' is clicked and strange stuff begin to happen rather than writing the new word or copying the text.

In the recording below, I am trying to replace the `WORD` with word `hello` but nothing is happening because insert is enabled:

[image]

It is a very annoying issue and I don't know why it is happening. How can I disable it?

P.S. I am not sure if that will help but I am using IntelliJ keymap inside Rider.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that this is an issue that is related to Vim.
I have both the problem mentioned above and the problems mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46488428/7981885 . Once I disble Vim by goto 'Tools' and unchecked 'Vim'. everything worked great again